# Associated Matrix to a Linear Transformation and Equivalent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

(Keep in mind that all of this information is prior knowledge to anything eigenvalue/characteristic polynomial related) So, according to my textbook (the university’s notes) any matrix with the same rank is equivalent (i.e. one another can be obtained through elementary row-column operations). It also states that: Let A be a matrix associated to a linear transformation *f* (which we are given in its explicit form). If and only if a matrix B is equivalent to A and has the same rank as *f*, B is also associated to the linear transformation *f*.

However, I’ve come across an exercise where the matrix associated to the transformation ($3×3$, and we are in $\Bbb R^3$) is equivalent (has the same rank, 2) to a B matrix (also $3×3$), but as I will explain now, B doesn’t appear to be associated to the transformation. Basically $B$ is a $M_b(f)$, $b=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ being a basis of $\Bbb R^3$. Its first column is $(1,0,0)$ and thus $f(v_1)=v_1$. However, when checking the equations for $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ there’s no possible vectors that fulfills this condition. Thus, and as it is hinted in the exercise, $B$ is not associated to *f* while being equivalent to A, the *f* associated matrix.

Am I getting something wrong or do the notes pose a contradiction?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151067/discussion-on-question-by-uberupense-associated-matrix-to-a-linear-transformatio); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate notions of equivalence at play here: one regards the matrix of a transformation relative to two separate bases (one for the domain and one for the codomain), and one regards a (necessarily square) matrix of a transformation from a space back to the same space. Matrices that are equivalent in the first sense are simply referred to as [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) to each other, whereas matrices that are equivalent in the second sense are called "[similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)" or "conjugate" to each other. You seem to have conflated these distinct notions.

As an example, consider the linear transformation
$$
f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2, \quad f(x_1,x_2) = (x_2,x_1).
$$
Let $\mathcal B_1 = \{e_1,e_2\}$ denote the standard basis, let $\mathcal B_2$ denote the basis $\{e_2,e_1\}$, and let $\mathcal B_3$ denote the eigenbasis of $f$ given by $\{v_1,v_2\}$ where $v_1 = e_1 + e_2, v_2 = e_1 - e_2$.

The matrix of $f$ relative to the standard basis is given by
$$
\mathcal M_{\mathcal B_1, \mathcal B_1}(f) = \mathcal M_{\mathcal B_1}(f) = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} = A_1.
$$
This is equivalent in the sense of your first paragraph (i.e. up to row and column operations) to the matrix
$$
\mathcal M_{\mathcal B_1, \mathcal B_2}(f) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} = I.
$$
These two matrices indeed have the same rank. However, these matrices are not equivalent in the sense of your second paragraph, and as such they do not encode the same transformation over $\Bbb R^2$. Indeed, the vector $v_2$ from above satisfies $f(v_2) = -v_2$, and correspondingly $A_1 v_2 = -v_2$, but there is no vector $x$ for which $Ix = -x$.

Now, consider the matrix
$$
\mathcal M_{\mathcal B_3, \mathcal B_3}(f) = \mathcal M_{\mathcal B_3}(f) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} = A_3.
$$
$A_3$ is equivalent to $A_1$ in the sense of your second paragraph. Correspondingly, there is a solution to the equation $A_3 x = -x$, namely $x = e_2$.